# How to find Xpath when it have same id ,class and type

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to Take X path for the below  mentioned code (Same ID &Class & Type)

```
<tbody>

    <tr id="mytr">
        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_10_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_20_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_30_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_40_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_50_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_60_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_70_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_80_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_81_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

        <td id="PanelTable" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenuYANTRA_MENU_KEY_90_0,this,'.menuitemp…al','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll');" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';"></td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: I can't see same 'ID' and 'class' in above code, and there is no 'type'. So better read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by node number, for example if You want to select third node, this will be something like this:

```
(.//td[@id='PanelTable'])[3]
```